# Delete [element] and [elements]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There seems to be no difference in the types of questions in each of these tags. At the very least, these need to be merged.

[element](/questions/tagged/element) **× 1074** [elements](/questions/tagged/elements) **× 525**

But they are extremely ambiguous and mean many different things, so perhaps something else needs to be done with them. They can't really be used by themselves, and don't add much value when they are applied. I think we should **delete both of them**.

I don't think it adds any value to [html](/questions/tagged/html), [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) or [xml](/questions/tagged/xml). Talking about any of these topics almost certainly involves elements.

- [element](/questions/tagged/element) **+** [html](/questions/tagged/html) **× 141**
- [element](/questions/tagged/element) **+** [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) **× 74**
- [element](/questions/tagged/element) **+** [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) **× 98**

Filtering out most of the common ones, [[element] -[jquery] -[javascript] -[xml] -[html] -[arrays] -[dom]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/element+-jquery+-javascript+-xml+-html+-arrays+-dom), still leaves several hundred with many different uses.

There are some existing tags that cover some of the common uses more precisely. But even some of these, like [htmlelement](/questions/tagged/htmlelement), seem fairly useless. [xmlelement](/questions/tagged/xmlelement) is supposed to be for the .NET object, but it's misused a lot. These might need deleting as well.

- [uielement](/questions/tagged/uielement) **× 84**
- [htmlelement](/questions/tagged/htmlelement) **× 83**
- [xmlelement](/questions/tagged/xmlelement) **× 62**
- [domelement](/questions/tagged/domelement) **× 51**
- <strike>[form-elements](/questions/tagged/form-elements) **× 19**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[alternate-elements](/questions/tagged/alternate-elements) **× 3**</strike> ****deleted****
- <strike>[object-element](/questions/tagged/object-element) **× 5**</strike> ****deleted****

Comment: Element is way too broad of a term to keep the tag. Anyways, **burn them all**!

Comment: At least there's no [tag:html-tags] tag... That means we're not w3schools... Oh my.. Just the thought makes me shiver...

Comment: @animuson comment is correct, element should be burninated.  There's no purpose to having it when it can mean vastly different things depending on context.  It usually means you need a more descriptive tag which contains the context in the tag (and doesn't rely on other tags to define it).

Comment: By the way, as this Meta site is used for the whole of the SE network, I have to ask, you are talking about StackOverflow, right? Not, say, Chemistry?